# How to test if a `Some[String]` contains some other string?

Tags: scala, matcher, specs2

Say I have a value which is `Some("aaabbbccc")`, I want to test if the value inside the `Some` contain some other string.

I tried:

```
val myvalue = Some("aaabbbccc")
myvalue must beSome(contain("bbb"))
```

It can't compile, but I can't find out a working one.

How to write such an assertion?

Comment: `Some("foo") must beSome(contain("f"))` compiles fine here.

Comment: You may add `;` to each matcher statement. Multi statements sometimes are mistaken as `method invoke` of the first matcher result

Comment: This compiles just fine with specs2 2.3.13. Which version do you have?

Answer (score 1):

You may run into such cases

```
None must be none
Some("foo") must beSome(contain("f"))
```

These two statements won't compile.

Compiler will complains

```
method apply in trait MatchResult cannot be accessed in org.specs2.matcher.MatchResult[Option[T]]
[error]       None must be none
[error]

                ^
```

Just put a `;` at the end of the first statement and everything will be fine

Comment: not sure why ; is needed here, works fine without (I tried the string equivalent but Option[String] also works fine)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a custom matcher like the following, taken straight out of the documentation: http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/matchers_quick_reference

```
val beOdd =
  Matcher { (left: Int) =>
    MatchResult(
      left % 2 == 1,
      left + " was not odd",
      left + " was odd"
    )
  }

3 should beOdd
```

That said.. perhaps there is a nice scala way of expressing what you're after.

I just saw the string include matcher, but how it could work with an Option[String]..?

```
string should include ("seven")
```

Ok.. got it:

```
option.value should be < 7
```

Which in your case would be:

```
myvalue should be ('defined)
myvalue.value should include ("bbb")
```

Comment: You are giving me an `scalatest` example. I prefer it, but I have to use the `specs2`

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> val myvalue = Some("aaabbbccc")
myvalue: Some[String] = Some(aaabbbccc)

scala> myvalue exists (_.contains("bbb"))
res0: Boolean = true

scala> myvalue exists (_.contains("abc"))    
res1: Boolean = false
```

You can adapt this easily to specs2:

```
(myvalue exists (_.contains("bbb"))) must beTrue
```

The real choice is in how you want the test to react in case `myValue` happens to be None. If you want it to fail on None, use the above. If you want it to succeed, use this instead:

```
(myValue forall (_.contains("bbb"))) must beTrue
```

In both cases, it will do the test you want on `Some`.